# How do I create apps that support all varities of "normal" screen sizes in Android?

Tags: android-layout, android

Normal screen sizes varies from 3.2 inch screen to 5 inch screen. 
How do i create apps that support all varieties of normal screen sizes only??

Consider you are creating calculator app with 5 buttons in row and 5 buttons in column and you are providing  button size of 50dp(width) and 50dp(height) then this looks really good on large screen but very big on 3.2 inch screen and if there are multiple buttons then on small screen, the buttons go out of screen. which is very problematic. It is so fustrating.

Any suggestion on how shall i do it?? 
I find official developers guide is pretty much useless as they haven't explained properly using examples.

I know we can have support of multiple screen sizes using

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml
```

but even in just normal screen size there is too much variation.

here is the example code from my application and consider all width and height to be 50. Please try below code and try running it on 4 inch screen, 3.2 inch screen , 4.5 inch screen. If you are using android studio then you can easily preview all screen sizes.

Sorry for my bad english and i am new to android UI programming though i have created basic apps in android but never done proper Ui programming.

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="@dimen/layout_normal_programmer_top_button_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/layout_normal_programmer_top_button_height"
        android:text="Binary"
        android:id="@+id/binary"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/decimal"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/decimal"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/decimal"

        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:background="@drawable/programmer_button_pressed"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="@dimen/layout_normal_programmer_top_button_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/layout_normal_programmer_top_button_height"
        android:text="Octal"
        android:id="@+id/octal"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/binary"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/binary"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/binary"

        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:background="@drawable/programmer_button_pressed"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="@dimen/layout_normal_programmer_top_button_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/layout_normal_programmer_top_button_height"
        android:text="Hex"
        android:id="@+id/hex"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/octal"

        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/octal"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/octal"
        android:background="@drawable/programmer_button_pressed"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/clr"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/clr" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="@dimen/layout_normal_programmer_bottom_button_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/layout_normal_programmer_bottom_button_height"
        android:text="D"
        android:id="@+id/d"
        android:layout_below="@+id/decimal"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/decimal"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/decimal"
        android:background="@drawable/programmer_button_pressed"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="@dimen/layout_normal_programmer_bottom_button_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/layout_normal_programmer_bottom_button_height"
        android:text="E"
        android:id="@+id/abs"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/d"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/d"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/d"
        android:background="@drawable/programmer_button_pressed"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="@dimen/layout_normal_programmer_bottom_button_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/layout_normal_programmer_bottom_button_height"
        android:text="F"
        android:id="@+id/f"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/abs"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/abs"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/abs"
        android:background="@drawable/programmer_button_pressed"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="@dimen/layout_normal_programmer_bottom_button_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/layout_normal_programmer_bottom_button_height"
        android:text="&lt;"
        android:id="@+id/del"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/f"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/f"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/f"
        android:background="@drawable/programmer_button_pressed"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="@dimen/layout_normal_programmer_bottom_button_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/layout_normal_programmer_bottom_button_height"
        android:text="C"
        android:id="@+id/clr"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/del"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/del"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/del"
        android:background="@drawable/programmer_button_pressed"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/and"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/and" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="@dimen/layout_normal_programmer_bottom_button_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/layout_normal_programmer_bottom_button_height"
        android:text="A"
        android:id="@+id/a"
        android:layout_below="@+id/d"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/d"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/d"
        android:background="@drawable/programmer_button_pressed"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="@dimen/layout_normal_programmer_bottom_button_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/layout_normal_programmer_bottom_button_height"
        android:text="B"
        android:id="@+id/b"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/a"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/abs"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/abs"
        android:background="@drawable/programmer_button_pressed"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="@dimen/layout_normal_programmer_bottom_button_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/layout_normal_programmer_bottom_button_height"
        android:text="C"
        android:id="@+id/c"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/b"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/b"
        android:background="@drawable/programmer_button_pressed"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="@dimen/layout_normal_programmer_bottom_button_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/layout_normal_programmer_bottom_button_height"
        android:text="OR"
        android:id="@+id/or"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/c"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/c"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/c"
        android:background="@drawable/programmer_button_pressed"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="@dimen/layout_normal_programmer_bottom_button_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/layout_normal_programmer_bottom_button_height"
        android:text="AND"
        android:id="@+id/and"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/or"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/or"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/or"
        android:background="@drawable/programmer_button_pressed"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/div"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/div" />
```

Comment: follow google IO code. Its good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid using set widths and heights, and don't clutter the screen with too many controls, it will only serve to make your application difficult for the user to navigate anyway. Wrap the content and use layouts to manipulate the positioning of controls within the layout. So instead of:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="@dimen/layout_normal_programmer_top_button_width">
    <!--etc-->
</Button>
```

Use instead something like this:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width=wrap_content>
    <!--etc-->
</Button>
```

Comment: what if you have multiple buttons with different text on them like "decimal" on first button, "+" on second then how am i supposed to set all of them to same size??

Comment: Give them a layout_weight of 1, and set the layout_width to 0dp instead of using wrap_content.

Comment: Please also note that your layout itself should use fill_parent or match_parent for layout_width and/or layout_height for this solution to work.

Comment: thanks, is it possbile to create textview with variable textsize??
same goes for edittext. size should change according to screen variations

Comment: Yes, setting the text size using 'sp' will handle this automatically. Please upvote answers that have helped you so others will know they are accepted answers. Thank you.

Comment: i cannot upvote due to less points but i have accepted ytour answer